# Unable to instantiate the URL

Tags: appium-android

I have written the first code for mobile automation, but stuck while instantiating the URL. Getting error

> "URL can not be resolved to a type"

```
driver=new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have correct import of URL class:

```
import java.net.URL;
```